# ScrollView rendering updated components without data in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flux, react-native-ios

I am having my page inside a **ScrollView** in react-native app. On first load the child components lets say multiple `TextInput's` render perfectly fine.

Each **TextInput** has a unique key.
When I start updating any of the TextInput field, the other components just collapse. By collapse I mean the component is present but will not show any data. The onPress event works on collapsed components but the text doesn't show up.

One way I found was to add a unique random `key` on every render but then the focus from the **TextInput** is lost, which is not a good user experience.

**Code**:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state= this.props;
  }

  buildList(data) {
    _.map(data, blog => {
      return(
      <View key={blog.id}>
        <Text>{blog.title}</Text>
        <TextInput
         placeholder={blog.label}
         onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
         value={value}
        />
      </View>
     );
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {
          data
        } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={mainStyles.pageWrap}>
        <ScrollView style={mainStyles.contentWrap}>
          <View>
            {
              this.buildList(
                data
              )
            }
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How onChangeText is defined?

Comment: @AlexanderGuschin, sorry for not posting the answer, I figured out that I had to add `style={{ flex:1 }}` to all the child components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went through the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html) and added **style={{ flex:1 }}** to each child component and that fixed it.

> In order to bound the height of a ScrollView, either set the height of
>   the view directly (discouraged) or make sure all parent views have
>   bounded height. Forgetting to transfer {flex: 1} down the view stack
>   can lead to errors here, which the element inspector makes easy to
>   debug.